# Проблемы с локализацией

Tags: laravel, controller, locale

Пытаюсь реализовать мултиязычность на сайте под laravel 5.4.

Локаль которую нужно показать получаю так

```
Route::get('setlocale/{locale}', 'HomeController@language');

    public function language($locale){

          if (in_array($locale, \Config::get('app.locales'))) {   // Проверяем, если у пользователя выбран доступный язык
            Session::put('locale', $locale);                    // Устанавливаем его в сессии под именем locale
          }

          return Redirect::back();
    }
```

Если в blade вставить `{{\Session::get('locale')}}`, то получаю нужное значение (скажем ru)

А если в __construct вставить такой код

```
if (Session::get('locale') != null) {
          $lang = Session::get('locale');
        } else if (Session::get('locale') == null) {
          $lang = "null";
        }
        View::share('lang', $lang);
```

, то получаю null. Ломаю голову, не могу понять почему !?

Естественно в контроллере подключены

```
use View;
use Session;
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять почему __construct не выдает значение `Session::get('locale')`. Спасибо заранее

Answer (score 0):

В конструкторе класса еще не обработаны Middleware, как раз в которой разбирается Сессия и Куки, поэтому там пусто.

Очередность обработки, если интересно вы можете посмотреть в фале Kernel.php

как вариант сделать так

```
public function __construct()
    {
    $this->middleware(function ($request, $next) {
               $this->locale = session()->has( 'locale' ) ? session()->get( 'locale ) : 'ru';

                return $next($request);
        });
}
```